# How do I find orphaned forks for a deleted gist or GitHub repo

Tags: github, git-fork, gist

Because the Twitter algorithm is Weird™️, [this super old tweet](https://twitter.com/nixcraft/status/491284625143001088) come through my feed very recently and I decided I'd like to try out [the gist it links to](https://gist.github.com/danielrehn/d2e6f2129e5f853c3166).

Unfortunately, sometime in the 5 years since that tweet was sent, the gist has either been deleted or made private<sup>**1**</sup>. Fortunately, I found the gist on [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190513012042/https://gist.github.com/danielrehn/d2e6f2129e5f853c3166). Problem solved! Right?

I could just copy-paste the file into a gist of my own for posterity, but  I notice that there were 25 forks as of the Wayback snapshot. According to [this documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility) it seems like...

> ...one of the existing public forks [should have been] chosen to be the new parent repository.

...assuming Gists have the same behaviour as vanilla repositories. Sadly, Wayback has not cached a list of who those forks belong(ed) to. If I want to follow along with that gist and its forks, how do I find them?

---

<sup>**1:** fwiw - it looks like the original author deleted their GitHub account very recently</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the forks by going to [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com) and copying a string from your wayback link in the search box (seeyouspacecowboy.sh).

This search provided me with [2 search results](https://gist.github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=seeyouspacecowboy.sh), one of which showed "25 forks". Clicking [that gist](https://gist.github.com/softdetours/d2e6f2129e5f853c3166) allowed me to see all [25 forks](https://gist.github.com/softdetours/d2e6f2129e5f853c3166/forks) of the Gist.